# Does delete chroot environment before umount /sys safe?

Tags: linux, chroot

I use chroot for some purpose and I also ran following command to mount some directory to chroot environment:
mount --rbind /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/

Then I want to delete this environment. But I was careless! I just exit chroot environment and just ran "rm -rf chroot_environment/". Then my shell gave out plenty out errors like "Failed to delete /dev/xxxx. Operation not permitted"

Then I unmount this two folder and then I could normally delete the chroot environment.

So will this mistake affect my system? Will files in /sys be deleted?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.